# Magento Shipping method and discount Label are blank in invoice

Tags: magento

I found a very strange thing in Magento 1.8. If the shipping address is the same as the billing address, shipping method and discount label show correctly in invoice and new order email. But if the shipping address is different from the billing address, shipping method and discount label show blank in invoice and new order email.

See examples here: http://i58.tinypic.com/fy3jg0.jpg and http://i57.tinypic.com/2afcwte.jpg

Answer (score 0):

It is looking like during the order creation some of your code does not allow you to save the data in the discount and shipping metods table respect to order.
Or I would suggest you to see the code for the email teplate inside the locale.